# Changes to user's home directory not updating

Tags: home-directory, users, chroot, sftp, sshd

I've just made changes to a user's home directory (using `usermod -d`) - but I'm still going to the old directory when I login (via `sftp`).

Do I need to restart a user service to pick up these changes?

(I've got the `Match user`... `ChrootDirectory` settings in `sshd_config` pointing to the parent of the user's home directory as well.)

JG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it sorted.

Short answer is no - you there is no user service to restart.

The issue was that the system wasn't configured correctly.

I've details the steps here: https://askubuntu.com/a/144093/2744