# Granting a sftp user access to a /var/www directory

Tags: users, sftp, www, sshd

I've created a user and made his home directory `/var/www/mysite/ftpdir`

I've also added a Match user entry for this user in `sshd_config` with a ChrootDirectory that points to `/var/www/mysite`

I've restarted `ssh` to pick this up.

When I log in with sftp - the user still goes to the user's old directory ie `/home/user`

What am I missing?

Comment: how about you symlink `/home/user` to the target?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the process:

1. Add the user to the group: `sudo usermod -aG www blub` as in [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to "/var/www"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)

   or just use `sudo adduser <username> www-data`
2. Install vsftpd `sudo apt-get install vsftpd`
3. Configure vsftpd for remote access: `sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf` and inside the file set

   ```
   chroot_local_user=YES
   ```

   and ensure this is commented out:

   ```
   #chroot_list_enable=YES
   ```

   as per [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages//lucid/man5/vsftpd.conf.5.html).
4. Restart nsftp: `sudo service vsftpd restart`
5. Configure the user's home directory to the web directory (not in `/home`):

   ```
   sudo usermod -d /var/www/mysite/ftpaccessdir <username>
   ```
6. Configure ssh chroot

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```

   add the following to the end:

   ```
   Subsystem  sftp  internal-sftp
   Match user <username>
       ChrootDirectory /var/www/site
       ForceCommand internal-sftp
   AllowTcpForwarding no
   ```

   and ensure that further up in the file that this is commented out (ie before the one you just added)

   ```
   #Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
   ```
7. Restart ssh

   ```
   sudo service ssh restart
   ```
8. Change the permissions for apache:

   ```
   chown root:root /var/www
   chown root:root /var/www/site
   chmod 755 /var/www
   ```

   As in the [docs here](http://jayeshjayan.com/?p=139).
9. Ensure that your directory has www-data access

   ```
   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/site
   chmod 755 /var/www/site
   ```

Comment: I have followed these instruction, but I got connection refused at end when I add these lines 
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

Match user <username>

ChrootDirectory /var/www/site

ForceCommand internal-sftp

AllowTcpForwarding no

Comment: I also have the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I have the same problem too!

Comment: How come at Step 9 you have `chown root:root /var/www/site` only to revert it back to `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/site` at Step 10 is this deliberate?

Comment: This is not working for me

Comment: What the point of `vsftpd` if you're configuring `sftp` access using SSH?

Answer (score 4):

I've a simple method and that worked for me for apache.

```
sudo useradd -d /var/www demo_user -g www-data
sudo passwd demo_user
sudo service ssh restart
```

That's it in case you still face permission issue use `chmod` and `chown` to address them according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting connection refused error at end then make sure that **"Subsystem sftp internal-sftp"** is place after **"UsePAM yes"**. If not then update and Restart ssh and it worked.