# Error conection ssh after jail user of ssh-sftp

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, chroot, sftp

What I want to:

I want to create a user to access to /var/www/laravel
I create a user demo, I followed this tutorial
    https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/how-to-add-linux-user-with-document-root-permissions/

I can connect and see the directory, folder, edit, open, upload, etc..
but I don't want to this user getout of this directory, or go to home or other directory...

when I follow a tuto about how to jail user

I followed this tuto
https://askubuntu.com/a/144093

at the end of the file

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I need to put this...

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
    Match User demo
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

and comment this line

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

PD: and restart ssh `service ssh restart`

but when I do that, I can't connect via ssh-sftp, I use Bitvise and it show me an error:

`windows error 10054`

http://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10235.aspx

My file /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
    # Package generated configuration file
    # See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

    # What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
    Port 22
    # Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
    #ListenAddress ::
    #ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
    Protocol 2
    # HostKeys for protocol version 2
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
    #Privilege Separation is turned on for security
    UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

    # Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
    KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
    ServerKeyBits 1024

    # Logging
    SyslogFacility AUTH
    LogLevel INFO

    # Authentication:
    LoginGraceTime 120
    PermitRootLogin without-password
    StrictModes yes

    RSAAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    #AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

    # Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
    IgnoreRhosts yes
    # For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
    RhostsRSAAuthentication no
    # similar for protocol version 2
    HostbasedAuthentication no
    # Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
    #IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

    # To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
    PermitEmptyPasswords no

    # Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
    # some PAM modules and threads)
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

    # Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
    #PasswordAuthentication yes

    # Kerberos options
    #KerberosAuthentication no
    #KerberosGetAFSToken no
    #KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
    #KerberosTicketCleanup yes

    # GSSAPI options
    #GSSAPIAuthentication no
    #GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

    X11Forwarding yes
    X11DisplayOffset 10
    PrintMotd no
    PrintLastLog yes
    TCPKeepAlive yes
    #UseLogin no

    #MaxStartups 10:30:60
    #Banner /etc/issue.net

    # Allow client to pass locale environment variables
    AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

    #Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

    # Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
    # and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
    # be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
    # PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
    # PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
    # the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
    # If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
    # PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
    # and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
    UsePAM yes

    Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
        Match User demo
            ChrootDirectory %h
            ForceCommand internal-sftp
            AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to SFTP connection](http://askubuntu.com/questions/674861/failed-to-sftp-connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is manual page for `sshd_config(5)` and it contains all information for all you want to set up your server. For you, there is important part about chroot directory:

> #### ChrootDirectory
>
> Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication.  **At session startup sshd(8) checks that all components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are not writable by any other user or group.**  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

This means that you need to execute:

```
chown root:root /var/www
chmod go-w /var/www
```

This is the answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32653528/5287072