# How to Create an SFTP-Only user in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, permissions, ssh, sftp

I am very new to linux, and I am trying to create an SFTP user that has full access to my wordpress installation which is at `/var/www/wordpress`. I want that when the user logs into sftp (via filezilla or similar) that his opening directory is `/var/www/wordpress`. I dont want this user to have access to the rest of the server; Only to the wordpress directory so they can upload/modify files.

I tried following the following directions, but they didn't seem to work.
[Link 1](https://gist.github.com/codinggirl/a4d5f0e32708d779881d5fbd5890abd8) and [Link 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143700/granting-a-sftp-user-access-to-a-var-www-directory)

Can anyone please recommend me proper directions of how to do this? I have been scouring the web for hours, but could'nt find anything that worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Redo your Search Engine research using the term "SFTP chroot jail." There are many good guides out there. We don't know what you already tried, nor why it didn't work, so some of those guides may be familiar.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking your time to reply. I googled that term exactly, and still haven't found any straighforward directions that work. I even got locked out of my ssh ftp user after trying one :(